# Help with conducting a priori power analysis to estimate sample size

Tags: anova, statistical-power, effect-size

Hy, I am replicating a study that looked into the effect that role models have on inspiration.

I am required to do a a priori power analysis to estimate what the minimum sample size would be needed. What I know from the study I am replicating is the following:

" The five adjustment items were combined into a single index of model’s adjustment (Cronbach’s  .98). A 2 (primed goal) X 2 (model type) analysis of variance (ANOVA) revealed a significant main effect of model type.2 The positive model was viewed as much better adjusted (M 8.19) than the negative model (M 3.14), F(1, 50) 339.02, p .0001. Neither the main effect of prime type nor the interaction was significant (both ps > .50) "

What I need to know is how can I conduct a power analysis based on that? im not sure what the effect size should be for that model nor how you arrive at conclusions for that.

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.